# Google Script to replace IMPORTXML(too big xml to import with IMPORTXML)

Tags: php, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to import a Google Shopping XML to a Google Spreadsheet, but Google Spreadsheet shows a error:

Error
Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size.

I need to import the data (and update it each 6 hours) and I don't know how with this error.

A example of what I using is this:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://avambu.xtechcommerce.com/datafeeds/google_shopping","//channel/item")
```

But with a larger XML.

There is a script or another solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but [XML Service Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/) seems to be Apps Script's way of handling XML files. "This service allows scripts to parse, navigate, and programmatically create XML documents." Check the guide for code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found for now is with a PHP script.

```
$filexml = 'GoogleProductFeed.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');

if (file_exists($filexml))  {    
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
   $i = 1;           // Position counter
   $values = [];     // PHP array

   // Writing column headers
   $columns = array('title', 'link', 'description', 'g:availability', 'g:price', 'g:image_link', 'g:product_type',
                    'g:google_product_category', 'g:condition', 'g:identifier_exists', 'g:id');

   $fs = fopen('GoogleProductFeed.csv', 'w');
   fputcsv($fs, $columns);      
   fclose($fs);

   // Iterate through each <item> node
   $node = $xml->xpath('//item');

   foreach ($node as $n) {               
       // Iterate through each child of <item> node
       foreach ($columns as $col) {         
         $values[] = trim($xml->xpath('//item['.$i.']/'.$col)[0]);
       }    
       // Write to CSV files (appending to column headers)
       $fs = fopen('GoogleProductFeed.csv', 'a');
       fputcsv($fs, $values);      
       fclose($fs);  

       $values = [];    // Clean out array for next <item> (i.e., row)
       $i++;            // Move to next <item> (i.e., node position)
   }
}
```

Thanks for @Parfait for the answer of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945425/convert-xml-to-csv-with-php-with-different-fields-in-some-itens/41949271#41949271) with a better PHP script to do this.

To the script run automatically, I need to use the CRON from a linux server.

Comment: How to implement php script to apps script?

Comment: I didn't implemented it in the apps script, I converted it to a CSV in a server and then make the Google Sheets read the file (it works better with CSV, even large ones).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using UrlFetchApp.fetch(); but please be aware that it is also limited to file size of 50MB. Please find my Google App Script code example below.

```js
// Import .xml
var url = "URL of .xml";
// Fect .xml
var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
// Parse .xml
var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
// Get root
var root = document.getRootElement();
// NameSpaces 
var atom = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
var base = XmlService.getNamespace('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
// Get all children (change "entry" and NameSpace to suitable fit)
var entries = root.getChildren('entry', atom);
```

###### Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app